# Getting mulitple columns for Group By from CAse-When-Then

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting an error Incorrect syntax near ',' for this query on line 
"when 3 then kle.Desc, kle.Num". What is the right format..?

```
select (case @Type
       when 2 then kle.JNum 
       when 3 then kle.Desc + kle.JNum  
       else kle.LNum end) AS VARCHAR) + @Q + CAST(count(sk.Id) AS VARCHAR) + @Q 
FROM    dbo.SK sk 
INNER JOIN K k  ON K.KITID = SK.KITID
INNER JOIN dbo.MLegend mtl ON k.Type = mtl.MType
INNER JOIN dbo.KLegend kkl ON mtl.KitType = kkl.KitType
INNER JOIN dbo.KExpiry kle on k.ExpiryId= kle.ExpiryId
WHERE SK.SId=Id 
GROUP BY case @Type 
    when 2 then kle.JNum 
    when 3 then kle.Desc, kle.JNum 
    else kle.LNum end, mtl.ktype
ORDER BY mtl.KType
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is comma in repeated case section.

```
select (case @Type
       when 2 then kle.JNum 
       when 3 then kle.Desc + kle.JNum  
       else kle.LNum end) AS VARCHAR) + @Q + CAST(count(sk.Id) AS VARCHAR) + @Q 
FROM    dbo.SK sk 
INNER JOIN K k  ON K.KITID = SK.KITID
INNER JOIN dbo.MLegend mtl ON k.Type = mtl.MType
INNER JOIN dbo.KLegend kkl ON mtl.KitType = kkl.KitType
INNER JOIN dbo.KExpiry kle on k.ExpiryId= kle.ExpiryId
WHERE SK.SId=Id 
GROUP BY case @Type 
    when 2 then kle.JNum 
    when 3 then kle.Desc + kle.JNum 
    else kle.LNum end, mtl.ktype
ORDER BY mtl.KType
```

Comment: It's ok your fix, but the entire query it won't work (the columns used in select)

Comment: @AdrianIftode Me neither, I was just clearing incorrect syntax error. I do not even know what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Yep!! That works and make sense too, but If I select two columns for ex. Select @Type when 3 then kle.Desc, kle.JNum I get an error in group by when 3 then kle.Desc, kle.JNum. What will the right fomrat for this?

Comment: One cannot select more then one column in case ... end because it evaluates to single value. Use another case for additional column, `case @Type when 3 then kle.JNum else null end`.